# Question about returning the right thing from recursive function (Leetcode 572)

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search

I am doing Leet Code question [572. Subtree of Another Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/subtree-of-another-tree/):

> Given the roots of two binary trees `root` and `subRoot`, return `true` if there is a subtree of `root` with the same structure and node values of `subRoot` and `false` otherwise.
>
> A subtree of a binary tree `tree` is a tree that consists of a node in `tree` and all of this node's descendants. The tree `tree` could also be considered as a subtree of itself.

I had a working solution. However, when trying a slightly different approach, I ran into a problem with my recursive dfs function. The structure of my code is this:

```
def isSubTree(self, root, subRoot):
    def dfs(root, subRoot):
        # some function that returns True when certain conditions are met

    if not root: return 
        
    self.isSubtree(root.left, subRoot)
    self.isSubtree(root.right, subRoot)
    
    if root.val == subRoot.val:
        if dfs(root, subRoot):
            return True
    return False
```

Basically, `isSubTree` explores all the nodes in the tree. Once it finds a node with the same value as `subRoot`, it compares the sub tree rooted at that node with the sub tree rooted at `subRoot` with `dfs()`.

I intended that when the `dfs()` function returns true, `isSubTree()` will also return true. If I've explored all the nodes in the tree (`isSubTree()` reaches the end) and `dfs()` hasn't returned true
at all, `isSubTree()` will return False.

However，my code always returns false seemingly because of the last line where it returns `False` (I've tested it and can verify that the `return True` part in if `dfs()` was reached, also I'm pretty sure my `dfs()` function is correct).

My question is, is there an elegant way to have my code do what I want it to do?

Comment: Your recursive function is invalid: it has no body. Is the indentation correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with the following:

```
def isSubtree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode], subRoot: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
    def dfs(r1, r2):
        # some function
        
        
    if not root:
        return False
        
    if root.val == subRoot.val:
        if dfs(root, subRoot):
            return True
        
    return self.isSubtree(root.left, subRoot) or self.isSubtree(root.right, subRoot)
```

Comment: Answering your own question is fine, but a good answer has an explanation of what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to see which code you are using, since obviously there is a syntax problem just below `def dfs`. Either the indentation is off or there is code missing (at the time of writing).

There are these issues:

- The returned value from either recursive `self.isSubTree` calls is not used at all. This cannot be right, as certainly you need that information to conclude anything about the work done.
- `if not root: return` will not return a boolean value when it kicks in. This should make the distinction between the case where also `subTree` is `None`: in that case the returned value should be `True`. Otherwise it should be `False`
- Assuming your non-provided `dfs` code is correct, it will deal well with the previous point as well (where one or both of the arguments is `None`), and will compare the node values correctly, so then `if not root` should not be performed *before* `dfs` is called, as `dfs` will take care of that.
- Similarly `if root.val == subTree.val` should not have to occur where it now occurs, but only in `dfs`.

Concluding, the working code could be like this:

```
class Solution(object):
    def isSubtree(self, root, subRoot):
        def dfs(root, subRoot):
            if not root or not subRoot or root.val != subRoot.val:
                return root == subRoot # Must both be None to have success
            return dfs(root.left, subRoot.left) and dfs(root.right, subRoot.right) 
        
        return dfs(root, subRoot) or root and (
            self.isSubtree(root.left, subRoot) or self.isSubtree(root.right, subRoot)
        )
```

Comment: oh I just left the dfs function blank here but in my actual implementation it has code in it. You can just ignore it.

Comment: What about my answer. Does it answer your question?